# static("/") {resources("files")} Route' is deprecated

Tags: ktor

The follow is deprecated but work.

```
routing {
    static("/static") {
        resources("files")
    }
}
```

When I write (https://ktor.io/docs/serving-static-content.html#index)
it does not work, I can not open the test.

```
routing {
    staticFiles("/static", File("files"), index = "index.html")
}
```

Comment: What error occurs with the last code sample?

Comment: I have a "HTTP ERROR 404 " error. But I found the answer, see below. Best thanks

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me with this:

```
staticResources("/", "static")
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it work, in the root path.

```
routing {
    staticResources("/", "files") {
        default("index.html")
    }
}
```